# Multiply large values from list all together

Tags: r

I have a problem with cross multiplying large values such that this error might appear:

> NAs produced by integer overflow

The solution would be converting the elements by `as.numeric`, however, I have a list and `do.call` cannot reproduce this, for example:

```
num <- list(Sweden = 167192L, Poland = 16223L)
do.call(`*`, num)
#Throws error
```

Expected outcome:

```
[1,] 2712355816
```

Comment: Does this exceed the largest integer value R can hold?  Run `.Machine$integer.max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `prod` on the `unlist`ed

```
prod(unlist(num))
[1] 2712355816
```

---

Or with `do.call`, convert to `numeric` class

```
do.call(`*`, lapply(num, as.numeric))
[1] 2712355816
```

---

The `NA` is not because of `do.call`, as it is a limit on the integer

```
> num[[1]] * num[[2]]
[1] NA
```